# Why "HereMap" shows blank screen In Android?

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

I Follow this tutorial [link](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps.html) for Nokia's Here Map integration. I got the output like this and error

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved
>   to unexpected implementation

[image]

My

> Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.heremap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<uses-library android:name="com.here.android" android:required="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.heremap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
android:value="XXXXXX"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
android:value="XXXXXX"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.heremap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.here.android.mapping.FragmentInitListener;
import com.here.android.mapping.InitError;
import com.here.android.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mapping.MapAnimation;
import com.here.android.mapping.MapFactory;
import com.here.android.mapping.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;

    // map fragment embedded in this activity
    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.init(new FragmentInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentInitializationCompleted(InitError error) {
                if (error == InitError.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center coordinate to the Vancouver region
                    map.setCenter(MapFactory.createGeoCoordinate(49.196261,
                            -123.004773, 0.0), MapAnimation.NONE);
                    // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max
                    // (with no animation)
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() +
                            map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
<fragment
    class="com.here.android.mapping.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Error Log:

```
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
 Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 com.example.heremap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5180) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-26 06:06:47.192:
 E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-26 06:06:47.192:
 E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
 02-26 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559) 02-26
 06:06:47.192: E/AndroidRuntime(808):   at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After remove jar from **order and export**  folder getting new error and updated log result

> 02-26 06:34:09.810: E/Trace(1266): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 02-26 06:34:09.859: D/BYD_Flex(1266): getValue()
>   name = @NOKIAFLEX@packageNeedData 02-26 06:34:09.859:
>   D/BYD_Flex(1266): Couldn't find file variant/cfg/flex.xml 02-26
>   06:34:09.870: D/BYD_Flex(1266): getValue() readFlexFromXml =
>   TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0} 02-26 06:34:09.870: D/BYD_Flex(1266):
>   getValue() name = @NOKIAFLEX@setDataUsageReminder 02-26 06:34:09.870:
>   D/BYD_Flex(1266): Couldn't find file variant/cfg/flex.xml 02-26
>   06:34:09.870: D/BYD_Flex(1266): getValue() readFlexFromXml =
>   TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0} 02-26 06:34:10.249: I/Choreographer(1266):
>   Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. 02-26 06:34:10.249: W/TextureView(1266): A TextureView or
>   a subclass can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled. 02-26
>   06:34:10.459: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 53 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 02-26
>   06:34:11.679: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 314 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 02-26
>   06:34:30.191: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 38 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 02-26
>   06:34:32.183: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 34 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 02-26
>   06:35:00.068: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 35 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 02-26
>   06:35:11.672: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 56 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Do you have an application identifier and an application token from the Nokia publishing tool?

Comment: @ManishDubey yes i got that and put those into manifest

Comment: Can you share your logcat details here? Are you making map in your app  by heremap services or porting Google Map to HereMap ?

Comment: Here Map is something new,Thanks for sharring nice question.

Comment: @Kedarnath Nice question got 2 downvotes unfortunately.

Comment: @ManishDubey i not seen error but display blank

Comment: thanks for help&support @Kedarnath and ManishDubey

Comment: Are you trying to display map on device or emulator? If emulator it must have OpenGL ES 2.0 and if device it must have working internet connection.

Comment: @ManishDubey  In Emulator,Nokia X not yet launch

Comment: @appubala, you should upload the code in question. It helps others to catch errors soon. Also upload the error logs.

Comment: @appubala Please upload Activity code and logcat details if possible. Issue may be in fragment.

Comment: @ManishDubey i updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi friends atlast i find the error,the errror is in the emulator,you must create emulator with this config[image]

After that add two jar in **libraries**

- com.here.android.sdk.jar
- com.google.android.maps.sdk.jar

[image]

and get **output** like this

[image]

Comment: Finally, problem was in emulator.It must be Nokia X Services based emulator.

Comment: @Appu, do I need to but publisher account to get Map-Keys ?

Comment: @Kedarnath to get key ->http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/nokia-apis/here-maps#keygen developer account is free

Comment: @appubala, I too successfully created Here Map Application. your answer helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Kedarnath it's only knowledge sharing,with all other's help only we spot out the error

Answer (score 1):

Your `minSdkVersion  is 8` but from [Official tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps/quick-start/creating-a-simple-application-using-the.html) they told to set `minSdkVersion to 11` see **POINT NO 6** if u want to access that map in `android-2.3 api level 10` then you have to use [Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

- Official tutorial :
  http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps/quick-start/creating-a-simple-application-using-the.html
- Support library :
  http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: i chaged that to 11 but not updated wait i update my question

Comment: clean and rebuild ur project once then run it

Answer (score 0):

In general you get the black-control when the map control initialization fails, so you could check the initialization complete function, and see whether the error code would indicate what goes wrong, quite often it does tell the exact reason.

Comment: i tried and correct my error,i updated my answer,thanks for support

Comment: i getting trouble with nokia console https://console.push.nokia.com/ not getting inside,shows 404 error in website

Comment: Try: https://console.push.nokia.com/ncm/Web/index.jsp I got forwarded to there when trying your link

Comment: it says enter your details after that continue button,clicking that 404 error,i am not able to work on NCM

Comment: Strange.. One trick would be to go to developer.nokia.com sign in with your account, and after signing in, try accessing the link.

Comment: And if that fails, then I would suggest emailing the support directly: notifications.support(at)nokia.com